# 8085 program to filter out positive numbers from a memory location

Tags: assembly, 8085

So i need to filter out the positive numbers and display the sum if it is less than FFH, if not display FFH. i typed the code in the simulator and use #DB to store the numbers in a particular memory location.
but when i run it step by step the memory content register is displaying 00. how to resolve it?

```
      MVI B,00
      MVI C,0A
      LXI H,4000

NEXT:      MOV A,M
      RAL
      JC REJECT
      RAR
      ADD B
      JC OVR
      MOV B,A

REJECT:    INX H
      DCR C
      JNZ NEXT
      STA 8070

OVR:       MVI A,FF
      HLT
# ORIGIN 4000H
# DB 28H, D8H, C2H, 21H, 24H, 30H, 2FH, 19H, F2H, 9FH
```

GNUSim8085

Comment: You should specify which assembler you're using.

Comment: Adding any two negative numbers will always produce a carry-out.  That's not the same thing as signed overflow.  IIRC 8080 / 8085 doesn't have a flag for that, so it's rather inconvenient.  But on any given addition, if adding two negatives produces a positive, that's signed overflow.

Comment: Also, `0xFF` is `-1`, the greatest/highest negative number (in 2's complement).  So the instructions are telling you to display the sum unless the sum is 0xFF, then display FF.  So you always have to display the exact sum, like with extended precision to handle a 2-byte sum?

Comment: Or are you supposed to only *keep* the positive numbers, not remove them, and treat the sum as unsigned?  That makes overflow detection and handling much easier.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'memory content register'? If you are referring to `M` it is not an actual register, it denotes the contents at the memory location pointed by the `HL` register pair. At the end of your code `HL` will have `400AH` and memory location `400AH` can hold any garbage value.

Since you are using a simulator where memory cells are usually initialized to 0, your simulator shows contents of `M` is 0 which is perfectly normal. What you should look at is the contents of register `A`.

Comment: another thing, I think `STA 8070H` should be written after `MVI A,FFH` in your code.